# use union type in onClick prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface, typescript-typings

i'm using react and typescript i have a interface that i define my types in that.in this file i have a onClick prop.this accepted a function as value.my problem is how can i define function overloads for my onclick prop.eg:onClick:()=>void | (number)=>void  ETC.
this is my interface file.in other words i want my onClick prop like my color prop can accept union type.

```js
import React from "react";

export interface IButtonText {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    leadingIcon: React.ReactNode;
    className: string;
    color: 'primary' | 'secondary';
    onClick: ()=>void;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Union type produces an error

```js
interface IButtonText {
    onClick: (() => void) | ((num: number) => void);
}


const foo = (props: IButtonText) => {
    props.onClick() // error, but should be ok
}
```

You are looking for intersection instead of union.

Intersection of function produces function overload.

Consider this example:

```js
interface IButtonText {
    onClick: (() => void) & ((num: number) => void);
}


const foo = (props: IButtonText) => {
    props.onClick() // ok
    props.onClick(2) // ok

}
```

This approach `onClick: (num?: number) => void;` in this case is perfectly valid, but if you have more than two elements in a union it can be hard to write correct function type with optional arguments

Comment: @Poldark this article might help you https://dev.to/captainyossarian/how-to-type-react-props-as-a-pro-2df2

Answer (score 2):

Just missing parentheses:

```
export interface IButtonText {
    ...
    onClick: (() => void) | ((num: number) => void);
}
```

But this might be better choice:

```
export interface IButtonText {
    ...
    onClick: (num?: number) => void;
}
```